# Associative arrays - grabbing specific keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this array:

```
$items = [
  'Mac' => [
    'quantity' => $qty1,
    'price' => 1899.99
  ],
  'Razer Mouse' => [
    'quantity' => $qty2,
    'price' => 79.99
  ],
  'WD HDD' => [
    'quantity' => $qty3,
    'price' => 179.99
  ],
  'Nexus' => [
    'quantity' => $qty4,
    'price' => 249.99
  ],
  'Drums' => [
    'quantity' => $qty5,
    'price' => 119.99
  ]
];
```

And I am wanting to only select qty1 and or 1899.99 at times, and other times I want to access any of other qty's and or their associated prices.

Right now I am trying:

```
<?php foreach($items['Mac'] as $x => $x_value): ?>
  <p><?= $x_value ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

which outputs:

> 1
>
> 1899.99

Above the 1 is the quantity of Mac's, and 1899.99 is the individual price, however I only want the quantity printed, not both.

How would I do this?

Comment: So don't use a foreach on the category subarray, iterate over the main array and then print only exactly what you want for each category? `foreach($items as $cat => $data) { ?> <p><?= $data['quantity'] ?></p> ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change your `foreach` loop

This:

```
<?php
$items = [
  'Mac' => [
    'quantity' => $qty1,
    'price' => 1899.99
  ],
  'Razer Mouse' => [
    'quantity' => $qty2,
    'price' => 79.99
  ],
  'WD HDD' => [
    'quantity' => $qty3,
    'price' => 179.99
  ],
  'Nexus' => [
    'quantity' => $qty4,
    'price' => 249.99
  ],
  'Drums' => [
    'quantity' => $qty5,
    'price' => 119.99
  ]
];


foreach($items as $key => $arrVal) {
 if($key == 'Mac')
  echo $key ."=". $arrVal['quantity'];
}
?>
```

The `if(){}` controls which `key` is getting printed so if you want to print
`Nexus` just change the value from `Mac` to `Nexus` or smthing and if you want to check multiple ones just use `||` like this `if($key == 'Mac' || $key == 'Nexus')`

`||` = `OR`

And if you want to get price just change `$arrVal['quantity'];` to `$arrVal['price'];`